# Hangouts not showing contacts, or after selected, their phone numbers

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google-hangouts, lg-g2

When I select a contact from "Contacts" and tap to send them an SMS, instead of their name, it only displays their phone number. If I try typing their name in hangouts, it doesn't come up at all! The contact is stored on my Google account and there are no duplicaes.

I'm on a Verizon LG G2 running Android 5.0.2 and Hangouts version  3.1.89134953